# Find the minimum number of tickets that have to be sold so that the number of vacant seats will be at most $1$ in flight $1$ or at most $3$ ...

Tags: combinatorics

There are $4$ commuter flights from city $A$ to city $B$ daily. For a particular day, it was noticed that the number of vacant seats on these flights are $8, 10, 13$, and $9$, respectively. Find the minimum number of tickets that have to be sold so that the number of vacant seats will be at most $1$ in flight $1$ or at most $3$ in flight $2$ or at most $6$ in flight $3$ or at most $2$ in flight $4$.

For flight $1$ we can have $0$ or $1$ ($2$ possibilities) vacancies. For flight $2$ ($4$ possibilities). For flight $3$ ($7$ possibilities). For flight $4$ ($3$ possibilities). So $16$ possible vacancies in total from the $40$ vacancies, which gives $40-16=24$ tickets to be sold so that there are at most $16$ vacancies. However, the answer is $25$. What am I missing or not understanding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of it this way - if you sold 24 tickets, you could get really unlucky and have 6 tickets go towards each of the four flights. This would result in 2 vacant seats on flight 1, 4 vacant seats on flight 2 and so on - in each case, we’re just one ticket shy of the required goal.

However, once you sell just one additional ticket (the 25th), no matter what flight this goes to, you’re guaranteed to have met the required quota.

Comment: omg that makes so much sense. It's a pigeonhole principle type of problem. I was so stuck on letting those tickets be picked exactly according to the conditions stated, but the tickets being picked are out of the total $40$ so we need $1$ more for it to be certain in all cases. Thank you so much!